# FlexSlider with multiple after method

Tags: flexslider

I have an include file with code:

```
$('#slider-HomePage').flexslider({
    ...
});
```

this file is included in other files. Each file has specific after FlexSlider method (fires after each slider animation completes):

```
$('#slider-HomePage').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
        console.log('here')
    }
})
```

Unfortunately after method seems to be ignored.

I use FlexSlider 2.1.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best but it works!

In the include file I use:

```
$('#slider-HomePage').flexslider({
...

start: function(slider) {
if ( typeof window['tracciaTelone'] === 'function' ) tracciaTelone(slider)
},
after: function(slider) {
if ( typeof window['tracciaTelone'] === 'function' ) tracciaTelone(slider)
}
});
```

and then in every file I use:

```
function tracciaTelone(sl) {
    var telPos = sl.currentSlide;
    var tel = sl.slides.eq(telPos);

    ... (specific code)
}
```